# Problem about cyclic quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

In cyclic quadrilateral ABCD,
let E, F, G, H be the orthocenters of triangles BCD, CDA, DAB, ABC, respectively. Prove that EFGH is cyclic.

#### Progress

So far, found that if  E   is orthocenter of BCD and F is orthocenter of CDA, then EF||AB.

Comment: What have you attempted till now?

Comment: I think I should solve that:

Comment: If E is orthocenter of BCD and F is orthocenter of CDA, $EF || AB$.

Comment: @user198223: You're most of the way there! If the sides of the orthocenter quadrilateral are parallel to those of the original quadrilateral, then how do the corresponding angles of the two quads compare?